# How can I delete data with specific row number (sqlite)

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I have a table people (name, address, phone), my table have 2000+ rows. I want to delete 1000 rows. How's about the query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you want to delete "first 1000 rows" given the unsorted order of the result of "select" query with no sorting arguments and no criteria, in which case you are doing something wrong.

But, as an academic exercise, here is how you'd do it. All rows in an SQLite have `rowid` field, which you can use to find where those 1000 rows end.

```
sqlite> create table t(s string);
sqlite> insert into t values('a1');
sqlite> insert into t values('a2');
sqlite> insert into t values('a3');
sqlite> insert into t values('a4');
sqlite> select * from t;
a1
a2
a3
a4
sqlite> delete from t where rowid < (select rowid from t limit 2,1);
sqlite> select * from t;
a3
a4
```

Answer (score 5):

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

If you had the SQLite update delete limit enabled

```
Delete from your_table 
where any_filter_you_wanted_as_well 
order by if_you_have_a_preference
limit 1000
```

Comment: I'm really feel frustrating when look at your query (sorry I'm sql newbie!) I try but I can't get the result.